# Feature request: review edits without diffs

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review, edit-history

I request that the review edits page allow the option to simply preview the original and edited versions side by side.

I've found the review suggested edits tool unhelpful because it only shows diffs; there have been a number of times where the diff logic breaks rendering and/or produces a complicated set of differences that make it difficult to perceive exactly what has changed... but if one could simply view the two versions side by side there would be no trouble comparing them.

---

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/62373) is a good example of why this feature would be useful. There simply isn't any way to view the edit that makes the mistakes immediately obvious.

And if the edit had actually gotten the paired $$ correct in the title, this would have made the question take up a gigantic amount of space on the main question list.

Comment: "Diffs" means "differences"?

Comment: I don't review many edits, but I vaguely remember a "Show rendered output" option... is not this what  you suggest?

Comment: @Jonas: Yes, "[diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)" is computerese for "formatted output showing differences between versions".

Comment: @Pavel: Unfortunately, that option tries to render the diff, which doesn't often work well when the math is the part that is edited.

Comment: Ideally the difference code should identify $\LaTeX$ marks and add its coloration tags *before* and *after* these. I don't think it's very difficult programming-wise to figure out whether or not the changes occur within a $\LaTeX$ environment.

Comment: This question needs more attention. It's rather irritating when seeing diffs involving LaTeX, even for simple cases like I just had with http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1295098/revisions.